# TikZ - Automata - Adjust bending of some overlapping edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to adjust some bending edge in the following output.
What is the best way to do that?

[image]

Here is the code that I use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}

\tikzset{
    ->,
    >=stealth', 
    node distance=3cm,
    every state/.style={thick}, 
    initial text =,
}

\newenvironment{tikzautomata}{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, on grid, auto]
}{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Exercice 3.3 -- Une solution (correcte ?)}


\begin{tikzautomata}
    \node[state] 
        (0) {$0$};
    \node[state, right of=0] 
        (1) {$1$};
    \node[state, right of=1]
        (2) {$2$};

    \draw 
        (0) edge[bend left, above] node{\texttt{inc}} (1)
        (1) edge[bend left, above] node{\texttt{inc}} (2)
        (2) edge[bend left, below] node{\texttt{inc}} (0)
        (0) edge[bend left, above] node{\texttt{dec}} (2)
        (2) edge[bend left, below] node{\texttt{dec}} (1)
        (1) edge[bend left, below] node{\texttt{dec}} (0);
\end{tikzautomata}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Do not use `arrows` - it is deprecated.

Comment: There's an option `bend angle` which is initially `30` (pity, not documented). Also you may define a semantic style like `long edge/.style={bend angle=45}`. Note `bend angle` should be set before `bend left/bend right`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ This gives a thinner control than the `bend left= 2cm`. Thanks for this.

Comment: @hpekristiansen What is the new way to play with arrows?

Comment: `arrows.meta` - see my answer and section 16.5 in the manual

Comment: @hpekristiansen Sorry for my question...

Comment: @projetmbc: No need for sorry or thanks on this forum - keep nice questions/answers, acceptions and votes coming and everyone is happy :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to write how you want to adjust it. Here is a guess:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    ->,
    >=Stealth, 
    node distance=3cm,
    every state/.style={thick}, 
    initial text =,
}
\newenvironment{tikzautomata}{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, on grid, auto]
}{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Exercice 3.3 -- Une solution (correcte ?)}
\begin{tikzautomata}
    \node[state] 
        (0) {$0$};
    \node[state, right of=0] 
        (1) {$1$};
    \node[state, right of=1]
        (2) {$2$};
    \draw 
        (0) edge[bend left, above] node{\texttt{inc}} (1)
        (1) edge[bend left, above] node{\texttt{inc}} (2)
        (2) edge[bend left=2cm, below] node{\texttt{inc}} (0)
        (0) edge[bend left=2cm, above] node{\texttt{dec}} (2)
        (2) edge[bend left, below] node{\texttt{dec}} (1)
        (1) edge[bend left, below] node{\texttt{dec}} (0);
\end{tikzautomata}
\end{document}
```

[image: Automata graph with arrows]

Comment: Good guess. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

It is simple to do with the `\ncarc` command from `pst-node`: you only have to choose the value of the  `arcangle` parameter, i.e. the angle between the arc and the nodes line:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-2.25)(9,2.25)
\psset{unit=4cm, arrowinset=0.15, radius=0.2} 
\Cnodeput(0,0){A}{\Large 0}
\Cnodeput(1,0){B}{\Large 1}
\Cnodeput(2,0){C}{\Large 2 }
\psset{arcangle=30, arrows=->, labelsep=2pt}
\everypsbox{\ttfamily}
\ncarc{A}{B}\nbput{inc} \ncarc{B}{C}\nbput{inc}
\ncarc{B}{A}\nbput{dec} \ncarc{C}{B}\nbput{dec}
\psset{arcangle=45}
\ncarc{A}{C}\naput{dec} \ncarc{C}{A}\naput{inc}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this `pst` solution. Thanks to `lualatex`, I am reconsidering the use of `pstricks` and folks.

Comment: Il est aussi très simple de compiler avec `xelatex`.